# Как в перегрузке метода Select Many сделать так, чтобы номер игрока прибавлял 1 и зависел от номера команды

Tags: c#, linq

Дан следующий код:

```
List<string[]> teams = new List<string[]>
            {
                new string[]{"Лионель Месси", "Криштиану Роналду", "Златан Ибрагимович", "Роберт Левандовский"},
//команда 1
                new string[]{"Мохаммед Салах", "Паоло Мальдини", "Франц Беккенбауэр", "Мишель Платини"},
//команда 2
                new string[]{"Йохан Кройф", "Лев Яшин", "Дэвид Бэкхем", "Диего Марадона"} 
//команда 3
            };

            int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            var result = ...

            foreach (var playerInfo in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(playerInfo);
            }
```

Что вводится:

```
15
```

Что получаем:

```
Лионель Месси играет в команде №1 под номером 1
Криштиану Роналду играет в команде №1 под номером 2
Златан Ибрагимович играет в команде №1 под номером 3
Роберт Левандовский играет в команде №1 под номером 4
Мохаммед Салах играет в команде №2 под номером 1
Паоло Мальдини играет в команде №2 под номером 2
Франц Беккенбауэр играет в команде №2 под номером 3
Мишель Платини играет в команде №2 под номером 4
Йохан Кройф играет в команде №3 под номером 1
Лев Яшин играет в команде №3 под номером 2
Дэвид Бэкхем играет в команде №3 под номером 3
Диего Марадона играет в команде №3 под номером 4
```

Реализуйте переменную result таким образом, чтобы получить список строк, содержащих информацию, в какой команде и под каким номером играет каждый игрок, если отсчет команд начинается с 1, а отсчет номеров игроков с n.

Вопрос: как реализовать отсчет с n так, чтобы когда заканчивался последний игрок команды, отсчет в следующей команде снова начинался с n

У меня получилось только сквозная нумерация, не понимаю как сделать так, чтобы программа понимала, что началась следующая команда

```
var FootballPlayers = teams.SelectMany(
    (players, index) => players.Select(player => new { p = player, i = index + 1, n1 = n++ }),
    (word, charsAndIndexes) => $"{charsAndIndexes.p} играет в команде №{charsAndIndexes.i} под номером {charsAndIndexes.n1}") ;
```

Comment: Вы многое скидываете на LINQ. Он вам должен лишь дать данные, по конкретному запросу (как запрос в базу, например), не более. Зачем вы его нагружаете еще всякими конвертациями? Вот если я вам скажу "дайте мне список игроков", вы мне ок,, вот, я смотрю и вижу всякие "играет в команде" и прочее. Ок, а почему это не часть класса? Вот есть объект `Teams`, почему я не могу написать `var firstPlayer = Teams[0]; firstPlayer.Team`, и мне на выходе дало команду, где этот игрок состоит, где я могу узнать тренера, матчи, и прочее. Но у вас все строками, через LINQ (а он медленный). И как бы это норм?

Comment: Я просто изучаю Linq через подобные задачки, и в них стоит задача реализовать решение через Linq. И хочется понять как именно через него можно реализовать подобное перечисление, которые заканчивают подсчет когда сменяется  массив

Comment: мудрить-неперемудрить, зачем просто, когда можно сложно? `teams.SelectMany((x, i) => x.Select((y, j) => $"{y} играет в команде №{i + 1} под номером {n + j}"))`. @EvgeniyZ вполне нормальный такой Linq получился.

Comment: Честно говоря сложно мне пока эта тема дается, не совсем осознанно получается все эти конструкции использовать, красивое решение, спасибо!